# jQuery dynamic css changing

Tags: jquery, dynamic

Why does the jquery not working in Opera and Chrome?

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
     $('link[href="includes/styles.css"]').attr("href", "includes/new_styles.css");
     $('link[href="includes/jmesa/jmesa.css"]').attr("href", "includes/jmesa/new_jmesa.css");   
 </script>
```

Comment: does it work with other browsers? Which is the error you're getting?

Comment: It works great in FF and IE.
Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'o.find' is not a function
Error thrown at line 12, column 5629 in <anonymous function: find>(E) in http://localhost:8080/.../jquery-1.3.2.min.js:
    o.find(E,this[0],F);
called from line 12, column 681 in <anonymous function: init>(E, H) in http://localhost:8080/.../jquery-1.3.2.min.js:
    return o(H).find(E)
called from line 12, column 128 in <anonymous function: l.$>(E, F) in http://localhost:8080/.../jquery-1.3.2.min.js:
    return new o.fn.init(E,F)

Comment: @krshekhar Again; do not use code formatting for this. 'jQuery', 'Opera' and 'Chrome' are product names - they are *not* code. They don't need to be highlighted in *any* way, please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out in `doc ready`: http://jsfiddle.net/YRC4N/

```
$(function(){
   $('link[href$="styles.css"]').attr("href", "includes/new_styles.css");
   $('link[href$="jmesa.css"]').attr("href", "includes/jmesa/new_jmesa.css");

   $('link').each(function () {
      console.log($(this).attr('href'));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 $('link[href*="includes/styles.css"]').attr("href", "includes/new_styles.css");
 $('link[href*="includes/jmesa/jmesa.css"]').attr("href", "includes/jmesa/new_jmesa.css");   
 </script>
```

Comment: Ok so troubleshoot more, can you move the script to the lowest end of the body? or just put this script inside $(document).ready();

Comment: Hmmm.. Ok lets troubleshoot more.. first you should check in other browsers if you can get the reference of the links in your script. I mean alert($('link').length); Then if you get the right count, alert($('link[href*="includes/styles.css"]').length). if you get zero, the try with alert($('link[href$="styles.css"]').length). I am waiting here.

Comment: FF and IE have found all link tags successfully.
In the Chrome console I have found this: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)} has no method 'find'.

Comment: Ok.. so can you show somehow your page? or you can click on 'view source' and send?

Comment: Thank you for help, but I have found the trouble - prototype and jQuery conflict ($ -> jQuery)